# Vue 3 reacts to deep change only once

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-reactivity

I have a deep nested data which renders my Vue 3 application. My reactive state looks like this

```js
import { reactive } from "vue";
import snapshot from "./snapshot";

export const state = reactive({
  snapshot: snapshot
});
```

And my watcher looks like this

```js
import { watch } from "vue";
import { state } from "@/store/state";

const consoleLog = () => {
  console.log("i reacted");
};

watch([state.snapshot.data[0].data.elements[0]], consoleLog, {
  deep: true
});
```

When i change the first (or any) element in my snapshot watcher reacts and console outputs "i reacted". But any following change does not react until i change anything on parent object.

What am i missing here?

Comment: not sure, but it seems to me you are only watching the first element the way you set up the watcher. Maybe try to use the whole `elements` array as the object to watch?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/watching-deep-prop-in-vue-3-lqrrv?file=/src/components/Demo.vue)